# Storing values of clicked buttons on arrays

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have a quiz that has multiple questions on different pages, I want to store the users answers in an array to later check if their answer is correct. The way the quiz is setup is that there are multiple parts of the quiz which all have their own page, but on these pages are multiple questions. Each question is shown after each other. Let's say part 1 has 2 questions, after an answer button is clicked the same page is loaded. The problem is that the values do not go into the array. Only 1 of the values is stored into the array, when the second question is answered the first value in the array goes away and only the second one is displayed.
    this is the code I use to store the button values in the array.

```
 <script>
 $( document ).ready(function() {

           var antwoordenObject1= new Array();
            $('.btn').click(function() {
                 antwoordenObject1.push($(this).val());

                  alert("newArray contents = "+ antwoordenObject1);

            });
       });
</script>
```

and this is my php code to display the questions and multiple choice answers:

```
<?php


$conn = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "kinderboekenweek");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM vraag  WHERE object_id_object = (SELECT id_object FROM object WHERE speurtocht_speurtocht_id= ".$SpeurtochtID."  AND id_object = ".$object.") ";
$resultVragen = $conn->query($sql);

$URL = "";


if ($resultVragen->num_rows > 0) {
                        while($rowVragen = $resultVragen->fetch_assoc()) {
                            $arrayVraag[] = $rowVragen['vraag'];
                            $arrayVraag = array_filter(array_merge(array(0), $arrayVraag));
                            $arrayAntwoord[] = $rowVragen['antwoord'];
                            $arrayAntwoord = array_filter(array_merge(array(0), $arrayAntwoord));
                            $arrayOptie1[] = $rowVragen['optie1'];
                            $arrayOptie1 = array_filter(array_merge(array(0), $arrayOptie1));
                            $arrayOptie2[] = $rowVragen['optie2'];
                            $arrayOptie2 = array_filter(array_merge(array(0), $arrayOptie2));
                            $arrayOptie3[] = $rowVragen['optie3'];
                            $arrayOptie3 = array_filter(array_merge(array(0), $arrayOptie3));
                            $arrayOptie4[] = $rowVragen['optie4'];
                            $arrayOptie4 = array_filter(array_merge(array(0), $arrayOptie4));
                            $arrayHint[] = $rowVragen['hint'];
                            $arrayHint = array_filter(array_merge(array(0), $arrayHint));
                        }
}


$result = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vraag WHERE object_id_object = (SELECT id_object FROM object WHERE speurtocht_speurtocht_id= ".$SpeurtochtID."  AND id_object = ".$object.") ");
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                        while($rowCount = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                            $arrayCount[] = $rowCount;
                            $arrayCount = array_filter(array_merge(array(0), $arrayCount));
                        }
}


if($_SESSION['qno'] < implode($arrayCount[1])){
    if($_SESSION['qno']>$arrayCount[1] && isset($_SESSION['qno']))
        $_SESSION['qno'] = 1;
    elseif($_SESSION['qno']<$arrayCount[1] && isset($_POST['vraag1'])){
       $_SESSION['qno'] += 1;
       unset($_POST['vraag1']);
   } elseif ($_SESSION['qno'] != 1 &&  isset ($_POST['vorige'])){
       $_SESSION['qno'] -= 1;  
   }
}





if($_SESSION['qno'] == implode($arrayCount[1])){
    $URL = "loading1.php";
}else {
    $URL = "speurtochtvragenpagina.php";
}

?>

<form name="exam" method="post" action="<?php echo $URL; ?>">


<?php echo $arrayVraag[$_SESSION['qno']]; ?>  <br>
<input type="hidden" name="vraag1" value="submit" />
<input id = "vraag1"  class = 'btn btn-default' type="submit" name="vraag1" value="<?php echo $arrayOptie1[$_SESSION['qno']]; ?> "> <br>
<input id = "vraag1" class = 'btn btn-default' type="submit" name="vraag1" value="<?php echo $arrayOptie2[$_SESSION['qno']]; ?> "> <br>
<input id = "vraag1"  class = 'btn btn-default' type="submit" name="vraag1" value="<?php echo $arrayOptie3[$_SESSION['qno']]; ?>">  <br>
<input  id = "vraag1" class = 'btn btn-default' type="submit" name="vraag1" value="<?php echo $arrayOptie4[$_SESSION['qno']]; ?>">  <br>

</form>
```

Comment: Submit buttons submit. Page refreshes, JavaScript is reset...

Comment: Your code is vurnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php), you probably want to fix that before making this application public :)

Comment: You can add `event.preventDefault();` or `return false;` at the end of your script, to prevent submit event.

Answer (score 1):

If you change page, your js data is cleaned.

You have to use a persistent data.

Check [local-storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Code is like this:

```
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you make the quiz as 1 page, you do not have to store anything, just make one ajax call to post the values and return the results.

Answer (score 0):

you can use map function to put multiple elements in an array , then check with the foreach loop with your matching criteria but you have to put event.preventDefault(); in the beginning of your js code !